# Polymorphism, using methods of child classes

Tags: c#, interface, polymorphism, abstract

I have an interface `IRecordBuilder` and an `abstract class Query` with a field `protected IRecordBuilder recordBuilder` and a method `public abstract IList<IRecords> GetRecordsFromResults();`.

In `Query` child classes constructors, I specify a recordBuilder concrete type depending on which child class I am in, for exemple :

`recordBuilder = new RecordsPerMonthBuilder(); //RecordsPerMonthBuilder implements IRecordBuilder`

I would like to use my `recordBuilder` field in the implementations of the abstract method above, but the properties in the implementations of IRecordBuilder remains unknown at compile time and i can't use them.

Besides transfering recordBuilder from mother class to each child classes and instantiate it there with the proper type, is there a way to make the polymorphism work here ?

Here are the explanations in code format :

```
public interface IRecordBuilder
{
  IRecords BuildRecord();
}

public class RecordsPerMonthBuilder : IRecordBuilder
{
   public IRecords BuildRecord()
   {
      if(Foo != null) return new FooRecord(Foo); // class FooRecord : IRecord
      return null;
   }
  public string Foo {get; set;} 
}


public abstract class Query
{
  protected IRecordBuilder recordBuilder;
  public abstract IList<IRecords> GetRecordsFromResults();
}


public sealed class ConcreteQuery: Query
{
  public ConcreteQuery()
  {
    RecordBuilder = new RecordsPerMonthBuilder();
  }

  public override IList<IRecords> GetRecordsFromResults()
  {  
     var recordsList = new List<IRecords>();
     recordBuilder.foo = "foo"; // IRecordBuilder does not contain a definition for foo
     recordsList.Add(RecordBuilder.BuildRecord());
     return recordsList;
  }
}
```

Comment: What is `Foo`? Is it some value that's specific to every record of that type? That seems to be right at the middle of the question. Which class should be responsible for determining `Foo`?

Comment: Yes, `Foo` here represent a specific property in that particular implementation of `IRecordBuilder`. `Foo` is declared in `IRecordBuilder` implementation but is "determined" (as in exist because of) the data returned by a specific `Query` implementation (basically if `Query` do a query that returns two strings and a int, there will be a `IRecordBuilder` and `IRecord` implementations that will hold two string and a int, with meaningfull names).

Answer (score 0):

I see three possible solutions for this:

**Option 1**: In your child class, cast the builder to the concrete type (since the child class created it, it knows the concrete type). If you do that, you might want to make the `recordBuilder` field readonly and pass it to the base constructor to ensure at compile time that its type cannot be changed.

**Option 2**: In your child class, keep an additional "strongly typed" reference to the record builder. (In fact, why do you even need the "interface typed" reference at all?)

```
public sealed class ConcreteQuery: Query
{
  private RecordsPerMonthBuilder myBuilder; 

  public ConcreteQuery()
  {
    myBuilder = new RecordsPerMonthBuilder();
    RecordBuilder = myBuilder;
  }

  public override IList<IRecords> GetRecordsFromResults()
  {  
     var recordsList = new List<IRecords>();
     myBuilder.foo = "foo";
     recordsList.Add(myBuilder.BuildRecord());
     return recordsList;
  }
}
```

**Option 3**: Make your base class generic:

```
public abstract class Query<TBuilder> where TBuilder : IRecordBuilder
{
  protected TBuilder RecordBuilder;
  public abstract IList<IRecords> GetRecordsFromResults();
}

public sealed class ConcreteQuery : Query<RecordsPerMonthBuilder>
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: Not directly related question, how can i loop in a `List<IRecords>` and do different instruction depending on the different concrete implementations (they don't have the same fields...)

Comment: @YthioCsi: Hard to tell without knowing details (maybe start a new question on that?), but option 3 could work here as well: You'd have a `List<TRecord>` instead of a `List<IRecords>`.

Answer (score 0):

One area of confusion is that your `Query` class depends explicitly on one implementation of `IRecordBuilder`, `RecordsPerMonthBuilder`. The interface `IRecordBuilder` doesn't have a `Foo` property, but `Query` depends on the `Foo` property. `Query` is hard-coded to only use `RecordsPerMonthBuilder`.

It's difficult to see the intent. One way to clear it up is to make sure that any interaction between `Query` and an implementation of `IRecordBuilder` is defined in `IRecordBuilder`. `Query` should depend on the interface and shouldn't call any properties or methods that aren't in that interface.

If only one implementation of `IRecordBuilder` requires a `Foo`, then that value shouldn't be coming from your `Query` class because `Query` doesn't know that `IRecordBuilder` needs a `Foo`. It shouldn't know what an implementation of `IRecordBuilder` *needs*, only what it *does*.

Here's a way to move it around. You'll see this pattern a lot.

```
public abstract class Query
{
    protected IRecordBuilder RecordBuilder { get; private set; }

    protected Query(IRecordBuilder recordBuilder)
    {
        RecordBuilder = recordBuilder;
    }

    public abstract IList<IRecords> GetRecordsFromResults();
}
```

Now it will never know what the implementation of `IRecordBuilder` is. That's good. It's now impossible for it to depend on anything that's not in the `IRecordBuilder` interface. Now `Query` depends on an abstraction, applying the [Dependency Inversion](http://scotthannen.org/blog/2017/04/26/dependency-inversion-for-beginners.html) principle.

What about `RecordsPerMonthBuilder`? It depends on a value, `Foo`. Will every implementation of `IRecordBuilder` need that? If so you could add it to the interface:

```
IRecords BuildRecord(string foo);
```

But if only one implementation needs that value then it shouldn't come from `Query`, because `Query` shouldn't know the difference between one `IRecordBuilder` and another. I can't answer that more specifically because I don't know what `Foo` is.

Another suggestion: If the inheritance between `Query` and `ConcreteQuery` gives you any grief, just don't use inheritance. Sometimes trying to use inheritance creates complications and doesn't give us any benefit in return.

Comment: I'll try to clarify the questions in the end of your post : All `IRecordsBuilder` have a different bunch of `int?` and `string` properties that are initialised with datas from Query classes (which execute DB queries) in `GetRecordsFromResults()`. `IRecordsBuilder` are justified by the idea that the `Query` should do queries and it isn't their role to process query result to desirable format for later, therefore i use a Builder pattern to create `IRecords` that hold meaningful bits of query results.. These properties in `IRecords` (and therfore in `IRecordBuilders`) aren't necessarily the same.

Comment: Also, only one instantiation of IRecordBuilder correspond to one instantiation of Query (QueryA should always have a RecordBuilderA and never a RecordBuilderB). If i pass the right recordbuilder in parameter of Query constructor, there is the risk someone could do `var queryA = new QueryA(recordBuilderB);` isn't it ?